# How do I guarantee sequential operation for shell script in ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I wrote shell script with bash in Ubuntu 13.10. But, it was not executed properly.

The shell script is

```sh
cp -a a/* b
cp a/.* b
```

The problem is that the Next commands which include Second command(cp) was executed before the First command was finished perfectly.

I hope that Anyone who knows this issue give me some helps!

Thanks!

Comment: No it wasn't. Try again.

Comment: Not possible. Commands in shell scripts BLOCK further execution, unless you force them into the background. `cp & ; cp` would work in parallel. `cp ; cp` would be done sequentially.

Comment: (`cp & ; cp` would be an error. `cp & cp` would be the correct form.)

Comment: However, remember that `a/.*` will evaluate to `a/.` (among others), which will - together with -a - recursively copy `a` again, so it might seem like the first command is still running.

Comment: What are the actual values of `a` and `b`? Is not `a` a subdirectory of `b` or vice versa?

Comment: hmmm... I tried several times, but seem not to be executed cp -a a/* b perfectly. The basis of this assumption is the size of directory b. When the shell script was finished, the size of directory b was same as executing only the second command.

Comment: @choroba Yes, a is not subdirectory of b.

Comment: when you say size of directory b, do you mean the output of `du -sh b` or the output of `ls -ld b` or output of `stat -c %s b`?

Comment: @MarcB 
I changed shell script bellow and tried it.

cp -a a/* b; sleep 10; cp a/.* b

It works fine.

Comment: @alvits ohhhh... I mistake, the basis of this assumption is size of .tar.gz file created by executing tar & gzip command on directory b.

Answer (score 1):

Your given copy operations are sequential, but you may prefer this in place tar for copy (the 'vv' is to be extra verbose) -

```
tar cfp - a/ | (cd b/ ; tar xvvf -)
```

Comment: Which has the additional benefit that special files won't mess up your copy. `cp -r` - which is implied by `cp -a` - is, was always, and will always be broken.